# Node.js: Send e-mails using AWS SES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-nodejs

Is there a stable module for Amazon SES in Node.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is your best bet

https://github.com/livelycode/aws-lib

Answer (score 8):

There is a new official AWS SDK for Node.js providing an API for every services. You should give it a try :

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me (optional parameters are commented out; constructed from the [AWS JavaScript SDK SES Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendEmail-property)):

```js
var SES = require('aws-sdk/clients/ses');
var ses = new SES({
  accessKeyId: "MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
  secretAccessKey: "MY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
  apiVersion: '2010-12-01',
  region: "us-east-1",
});

var params = {
  Destination: {
    // BccAddresses: [
    //   'STRING_VALUE',
    //   /* more items */
    // ],
    // CcAddresses: [
    //   'STRING_VALUE',
    //   /* more items */
    // ],
    ToAddresses: [
      'MY_PERSONAL_EMAIL@gmail.com',
    ]
  },
  Message: {
    Body: {
      Html: {
        Data: '<b>hello world</b>',
        Charset: 'utf-8'
      },
      Text: {
        Data: 'hello world',
        Charset: 'utf-8'
      }
    },
    Subject: {
      Data: 'hello subject',
      Charset: 'utf-8'
    }
  },
  Source: 'MY_EMAIL_REGISTERED_WITH_SES@MYDOMAIN.COM',
  // ConfigurationSetName: 'STRING_VALUE',
  // ReplyToAddresses: [
  //   'STRING_VALUE',
  //   /* more items */
  // ],
  // ReturnPath: 'STRING_VALUE',
  // ReturnPathArn: 'STRING_VALUE',
  // SourceArn: 'STRING_VALUE',
  // Tags: [
  //   {
  //     Name: 'STRING_VALUE',
  //     Value: 'STRING_VALUE'
  //   },
  //   /* more items */
  // ]
};
ses.sendEmail(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ***Official*** `aws-sdk` node module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

The **API docs** are good: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html

But, if you need a ***complete step-by-step example***, we wrote one:
https://github.com/dwyl/sendemail
(*we are using this in several projects and it works well for us*)

Answer (score 1):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var smtpConfig = {
    host: 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL 
    auth: {
        user: 'userName',
        pass: 'password'
    }
};
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

app.get('/sendMail', function (req, res) {
    transport.sendMail({
    from: 'youremail@localhost.com',
    to: 'recipient@localhost.com',
    subject: 'My Amazon SES Simple Email',
    text: 'Amazon SES is cool'
  },function(error, data){

      if(error){
          res.status(403).json({message:error});
      }
      if(data){
          res.end('mail sent');
      }
  });


})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port

   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try AwsSum which gives you a lot more help than the other libraries.

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/

Note: I'm the author of AwsSum and again, it's actively maintained, unlike some of the other AWS libraries out there for Node.js. :)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, widely used NodeMailer module can be used to send SES email. Can check out this gist to send email with zip attachment: https://gist.github.com/munim/02e1bc10bf4e0fbb17c5bf6689906a8a